# Sorting timestamps by month with key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I am trying to sort "timestamps" by the month *only*. Right now the code is:

```
arr = ["13-16", "5-15", "9-15", "3-14", "12-19", "11-19", "9'19", "5-14"]
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda str:(str.split("-")[0]))
print(arr)
```

However, what I am getting when I print is this:

```
['11-19', '12-19', '13-16', '3-14', '5-15', '5-14', '9-15', '9-19']
```

Does anyone know why Python is ordering this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast your month to an `int` otherwise keys are sorted as strings, that is alphabetically.

I also recommend you do not throw away the year so sorting dates of same months resolves in a well-defined order.

```
arr = ["13-16", "5-15", "9-15", "3-14", "12-19", "11-19", "9-19", "5-14"]
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda s: [int(x) for x in s.split("-")])
#                                ^ cast to an int
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['3-14', '5-14', '5-15', '9-15', '9-19', '11-19', '12-19', '13-16']
```

Answer (score 1):

✓ **@Goldberg**, the output `['3-14', '5-15', '5-14', '9-15', '9-19', '11-19', '12-19', '13-16']` looks ok but still it's not in proper order as the correct one is `['3-14', '5-14', '5-15', '9-15', '9-19', '11-19', '12-19', '13-16']` that you can get using below code:

> Based on the concept of comparison of tuples:
>
> `a = (3, 14)`
>
> `b = (5, 14)`
>
> `c = (5, 15)`
>
> `print (a < b) # True`
>
> `print (c > b) # True`
>
> `print (a > c) # False`

#### » Right way (correct output)

```
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda str:( int(str.split("-")[0]), int(str.split("-")[1])))
print(arr)
# ['3-14', '5-14', '5-15', '9-15', '9-19', '11-19', '12-19', '13-16']
```

#### » Wrong way (incorrect output)

```
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda str:( int(str.split("-")[0])))
print(arr)
# ['3-14', '5-15', '5-14', '9-15', '9-19', '11-19', '12-19', '13-16']
```